# Load a XML file from a specific folder in Android

Tags: java, android

I have three XML files that I'd like to call from my app. I'd like to save those files in internal app-specific directory `/data/data/your.package.name/`, but I don't know where is that folder, or if is there another folder to put them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access them like this :

```
Context ctx = ...; // Retrieve your application context for instance
File xml1 = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), "file1.xml");
```

If you want to modify them :

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileOutput("file1.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: But, which folder do I have to put them?

Comment: The folder is `ctx.getFilesDir()`. Use the API and not any hard coded path.

Comment: FYI: The folder will then be /data/data/your.package.name/files. Check first if it exists before using openFileOutput.

Comment: Ok. I figure it out to put the files into that folder. Thanks @ToYonos